# Merging two lists in to one list using java

Tags: list, merge

I have employee details as below. I need to merge this details based on the id.

````
Employee e1 = new Employee(1,20.5, "REGULAR")
Employee e2 = new Employee(2,22.5,"REGULAR")
Employee e3 = new Employee(3, 24.5,"CONTRACT")
List<Employee> employee1 = [e1,e2,e3]

Employee e4 = new Employee(4,20.5, "REGULAR")
Employee e5 = new Employee(2,22.5,"REGULAR")
Employee e6 = new Employee(5, 24.5,"CONTRACT")
List<Employee> employee2 = [e4,e5,e6]

Final result should be as List<Employee> employee3 = [e1,e2,e3,e4,e6] ```

Here e2 and e5 are having same details. We need to merge them and add it to e2 only with below details
Employee e2 = new Employee(2,45,"REGULAR")

45 is sum of e2 and e5.
````

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to this question:

1. **Merging two lists**: this is easily done using `addAll()` method.
2. **Custom Aggregation if `Employee` object value are the same**: there are multiple ways of doing this.

   2.1 **Using a `Set` container and defining `Equals` and `HashCode` for `Employee` object**: you can put all the elements from one list into a `HashSet` and then add elements from the second list while checking if the element already exists in the `HashSet`. If it does, you can remove it and aggregate the values as you would like into a new element and add it to a set.

   ```java
   Employee e1 = new Employee(1,20.5, "REGULAR")
   Employee e2 = new Employee(2,22.5,"REGULAR")
   Employee e3 = new Employee(3, 24.5,"CONTRACT")
   Set<Employee> employee1 = [e1,e2,e3]

   Employee e4 = new Employee(4,20.5, "REGULAR")
   Employee e5 = new Employee(2,22.5,"REGULAR")
   Employee e6 = new Employee(5, 24.5,"CONTRACT")
   List<Employee> employee2 = [e4,e5,e6]

   for (Employee employee : employee2) {
        if (employee1.contains(employee)) {
            // or some other logic
            employee1.remove(employee)
            // assuming for new Employee(1,20.5, "REGULAR")
            // 1 is SerialNumber, 20.5 is Pay and "REGULAR" is 
            // EmploymentType
            employee1.add(new Employee(employee.getSerialNumber, 
                employee.getPay()*2, employee.getEmployementType()));
        }
   }
   // convert back to ArrayList if you want
   List<String> employee3 = new ArrayList<String>();
   employee3.addAll(employee1);
   ```

   2.2 **Create a Custom Container**: create a custom container with `add` method that verifies whether the object exists and if it does, then the method does some aggregation for you. This is similar to 2.1 but the usage (`customContainer.add()`) would be neater.